# Vue.js input (checkbox radio) does not toggle when using :checked with @input or @click together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/359940/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label>                   
    <input 
    type="checkbox"
            name="demo"
    :checked="isChecked"
            @input="someMeth('A')" 
    value="A"/> 
    A
 </label>
 <label>
    <input
    type="radio" 
    name="demo"
    :checked="isChecked"
    @input="someMeth('B')" 
    value="B"/> 
    B
 </label>
 <div>
  {{somedata}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Clicking on input(checkbox or radio) does not toggle its status.

Remove either :checked or @input would solved the problem.

but I need them both.

@click does the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

in vue.js,checkbox's value is bind using `v-model`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checktype: 'checkbox',
    somedata: [],
    isChecked: false,
    isChecked2: false,
  },
  methods: {
   someMeth(val) {
      this.somedata.push(val)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
    <label>
        <input 
            :type="checktype"
            :name="demo"
            v-model="isChecked"
            @input="someMeth('A')" 
            value="A"/> 
            A
    </label>
    <lable>  
        <input
            :type="checktype" 
            :name="demo"
            v-model="isChecked2"
            @input="someMeth('B')" 
            value="B"/> 
            B
    </lable>
    <div>
        {{somedata}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using :checked because it's 'pre-checked' status from a method. I have other situation using :checked and v-model together, like a radio, it's working fine.

Comment: If you use `v-model`, you don't need `:checked` coz v-model does for checking status @chriszhxi

Comment: v-model is 2-way binding, :checked it's just the initial status, this status does not change.

Comment: This is definitely the answer @chriszhxi, please make sure you're following the implementation example Kaicui provided